# Blank SWF file and no errors when compiling ActionScript 3.0 class through mxmlc compiler

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have two action-script classes one is instantiated in the other. It works fine in flash professional cc but when I use the mxmlc compiler via the command prompt, it compiles a blank swf without any errors.

Monster.as

```
package {
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundMixer;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Monster extends Sprite {
        public function Monster() {
            // constructor code
            var imageLoader: Loader = new Loader();
            var image: URLRequest = new URLRequest("female-monster.png");
            imageLoader.load(image);
            addChild(imageLoader);
            imageLoader.x = 0;
            imageLoader.y = 0;
        }
        public function roar():void {
            var mySound: Sound = new Sound();
            mySound.load(new URLRequest("monster.mp3"));
            mySound.play();
        }
        public function visibleMonster():void {
            this.alpha = .5;
        }

    }

}
```

addMonster.as

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import Monster;

    public class addMonster extends MovieClip {
        public var monster:Monster;

        public function addMonster() {
            // constructor code
            monster = new Monster();
            addChild(monster);

            monster.roar();
            monster.moveMonster();
            monster.visibleMonster();
        }

    }

}
```

Is it possible that there are options I need to use when running the command to compile?

Comment: show us the command that you are using in the mxmlc compiler. More info here > http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7fe9.html. I think you have to have Application.mxml file or else it wont compile, looks like you dont have a application.mxml file. this is more like a entry point to the application.

Comment: the command I was using was                             C:\Flex_SDK\bin\mxmlc C:\wamp\www\Prototype\addMonster.as     I discovered that the problem was that I had the files open in other applications  (dreamweaver and flash) while I was running the command once I closed the other applications it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by closing Dreaweaver and Flash applications which were using the file I was trying to run mxmlc compiler to compile the as file.